# Spring WebFlux: How to route to a different handler function based on query parameters?

Tags: spring, functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am writing a person API using Spring WebFlux functional programming, how to route to different handler functions based on the query param names?

```
    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> route(PersonHandler personHandler) {
        return RouterFunctions.route(GET("/people/{id}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), personHandler::get)
                .andRoute(GET("/people").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), personHandler::all)
                .andRoute(GET("/people/country/{country}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), personHandler::getByCountry)
//                .andRoute(GET("/people?name={name}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), personHandler::searchByName)
//                .andRoute(GET("/people?age={age}").and(accept(APPLICATION_JSON)), personHandler::searchByAge)
//                I am expecting to do something like this
                ;
    }
```

Or do I need to handle it in the handler function? 
like

```java
    public Mono<ServerResponse> searchPeople(ServerRequest serverRequest) {
        final Optional<String> name = serverRequest.queryParam("name");
        final Optional<String> age = serverRequest.queryParam("age");
        Flux<People> result;

        if(name.isPresent()){
            result = name.map(peopleRepository::searchByName)
                    .orElseThrow();
        } else if(age.isPresent()){
            result = name.map(peopleRepository::searchByage)
                    .orElseThrow();
        }

        return ok().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(result, People.class);
    }
```

What is the best way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own `RequestPredicate` and use the existing infrastructure (by plugging it into a `and()`):

```
public static RequestPredicate hasQueryParam(String name) {
  return RequestPredicates.queryParam(name, p -> StringUtils.hasText(p));
}
```